# error: invalid conversion from ‘Node*’ to ‘int’

Tags: c++

Working in C++ here. I am trying to develop a specific program that creates a BST from its preorder traversal. Here's the first batch of code:

```
class Node {

 private:
   int val;     
   Node *left;      
   Node *right;     

 public:
   Node () : val(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}         
   Node (int v) : val(v), left(NULL), right(NULL) {} 
   Node (int v, Node *l, Node *r) : val(v), left(l), right(r) {}
   Node& operator = (Node& rhs) {               
     if (&rhs == this) return *this;
     val = rhs.val;
     left = rhs.left;
     right = rhs.right;
     return *this;
   }

}*root;
```

I've taken out some of the functions but that's the basics. Now here's the other piece of code:

```
Node *temp = new Node();

  if (preorder[trav] <= N)
  {
     temp = root;
     root->goLeft(pre_ordered, traverse);
     traverse++;
  }

  else
  {
     temp = root;
     root->goRight(pre_order, traverse);
     traverse++;
  }
```

However, I then get " error: invalid conversion from 'Node*' to 'int' " on the line "temp = root". Any ideas? It seems to me I'm setting one node equal to the other so I don't understand what's wrong. Looked online and found nothing helpful. Some similar errors, but just different enough to not be useful.

I'll be upfront that this is for a school assignment so I'm not looking for direct answers. Just hints about what I need to change or where I need to look would be great! Thanks.

**EDIT**: Exact error is:

```
main.cpp:160:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘Node*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
      temp = root;
           ^
```

**EDIT** I found it. I apologize.

I was stupid and didn't look hard enough to find that I was redefining "temp" as an int in the main function. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Can't answer my own question since not enough rep.

Comment: Give us more context around your second bit of code - at least the enclosing function.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/RNh8JD), once I fix the wrong member names. Could you post a test case that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Your code does not have `left` and `right` declared. Is it `left_child` and `right_child`? Also, why would you create a new `Node` then lose it by assigning `root`?

Comment: When I change the names of the data members to `val`, `left`, and `right` to match the rest of your code, add `#include <cstddef>` to make `NULL` visible, your code compiles without error. Show us the actual code (copy-and-paste it) that exhibits that error.

Comment: Just as a matter of style, I wouldn't combine the `class` definition with an object definition. I'd define the class, then write `Node& root;` separately.

Comment: Ah gosh! Yea sorry guys my bad. It is val, left, and right in my real code but I switched it up to make it more clear. Should have double checked. Even with the same names though, I still get the same error.

Comment: please give us a SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: Even after putting in #include <cstddef> and fixing the names, no luck. I'll edit the post with the exact error.

Comment: Which is why you should never type code directly into your question. Compile it on your own system (perhaps after trimming it down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem), then copy-and-paste from your source file into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the members you have declared do not match what you used in the code. For example, you declared `int value` but reference it by the name `val`

Corrected code that compiles is:

```
class Node {

 private:
   int val;       
   Node *left;        
   Node *right;       

 public:
   Node () : val(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}         
   Node (int v) : val(v), left(NULL), right(NULL) {} 
   Node (int v, Node *l, Node *r) : val(v), left(l), right(r) {}
   Node& operator = (Node& rhs) {               
     if (&rhs == this) return *this;
     val = rhs.val;
     left = rhs.left;
     right = rhs.right;
     return *this;
   }

}*root; 

int main()
{
    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp = root;
    return 0;
}
```

I know you didn't want a direct answer, but it seemed like an actual mistake, and not a lack of understanding.

Comment: But the code in the question doesn't exhibit the problem the OP described.

Comment: @KeithThompson If op updates his question and my answer is no longer valid I will update it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but yea, that wasn't the problem. Fixed the code now. Thanks anyways though!